# Перемещение курсора по экрану терминала в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Нужно реализовать перемещение курсора по экрану терминала при помощи клавиш стрелок (без библиотек на подобии ncurses). Но при использовании циклов и/или `time.sleep()` вывод пропадает и появляется только после завершения программы.
Вот что я делаю:

```py
import sys, os
import time

from getch import getch

class Console:
    size = os.get_terminal_size()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def clear_screen():
        sys.stdout.write("\033[H\033[J")
    def set_cursor_at(y, x):
        sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{y};{x}H")
    def move_cursor_forward(n):
        sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{n}C")
    def move_cursor_backward(n):
        sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{n}D")
    def move_cursor_up(n):
        sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{n}A")
    def move_cursor_down(n):
        sys.stdout.write(f"\033[{n}B")

def main(argv):
    Console.clear_screen()
    Console.set_cursor_at(1,1)
    print("Hello, World", end='')
    Console.move_cursor_forward(5)
    print("Now I'm here!", end='')
    while True:
        ch = getch()
        if ord(ch) == 27:
            group = getch()
            key = getch()
            if ord(key) == 68: Console.move_cursor_backward(1)
            if ord(key) == 67: Console.move_cursor_forward(1)
            if ord(key) == 65: Console.move_cursor_up(1)
            if ord(key) == 66: Console.move_cursor_down(1)
            #print(ord(key))
        else:
            if ch == 'q': break
    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Код getch.py:

```py
def getch():
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
```

Comment: А почему "без библиотек на подобии ncurses"? Искусственное ограничение для учебной задачи или реальная необходимость?

Comment: @MiniMax 1-ое. Мне интересно как работают такие библиотеки под капотом, но чужой код на Си читать трудновато, хотя я не плохо знаю Си, просто кода много и долго вникать что и где... И на этот вопрос я уже ответил. Другой вопрос - как сделать виджет многострочного ввода? Это единственный виджет, с которым проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Уже решил:
`sys.stdout.flush()` после каждого вывода на экран, в том числе, и после вывода escape-последовательностей для перемещения курсора.